# How to delete iconTint in bottom nav menu

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bottomnav

I am making my app. I used preset from Android Studio with 3 items in bottom nav menu. Then I modified it for 5 items, add new fragments and so on. Also I downloaded my icons and add selectors to change icon of active item. But there is a problem. I see that all code work and icon changes, but I cant see my  new icon, as icontint make all purple. I tried to change icon tint to null in different parts of code, but nothing helped.

This is my colors.xml

```xml
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

This is my themes.xml

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Myth" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

bottom_nav_menu.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_new"
        android:icon="@drawable/new_selector"
        android:title="@string/title_new" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_bonus"
        android:icon="@drawable/bonus_selector"
        android:title="@string/title_bonus" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_selector"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_selector"
        android:title="@string/title_menu" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile_selector"
        android:title="@string/title_profile" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Please add your bottom navigation XML code to make it more clear

Comment: Added. If you need anything more, I am waiting

Comment: try with "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"

Comment: Thanks, but not. Now it crashes after start

Comment: Where did you put it and what's crash message

Comment: Also try "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar". It could be that you have actionBar set so it crashes because you say that you won't use it with "NoActionBar"

Comment: You should understand that this parent theme defines its own styles and colors depending on specified ones. So it can clash with what you try to recolor in your custom XML. You can also try to use non-material theme for your bottom navigation items by specifying style="@styles/AppTheme"